# Scala String indexOf Character from the Right Side

Tags: scala

**What is an idiomatic way to find the index of a `Char` in a scala `String` starting from the right side of the String (instead of starting from the left side using `indexOf`)?**

Examples:

```
def indexOfFromRight(s: String, c: Char): Int = ???

assert(indexOfFromRight("iii", 'i') == 2)

assert(indexOfFromRight("abbabb", 'a') == 3)

assert(indexOfFromRight("foobar", 'x') == -1)
```

Thank you in advance for your consideration and response.

Comment: Using `lastIndexOf` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf-int-

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Thanks!  I kept searching for rightfind or rfind (similar to python).  Didn't think of "last".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented: the [`lastIndexOf`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/collection/immutable/StringOps.html#lastIndexOf(elem:Char,end:Int):Int) method of String accomplishes the right side find.